# How to use Google Play Leaderboards in Xamarin / Monogame

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, monogame

Ok this is a simple question, but the Xamarin forums are pretty much useless...

**I am trying to implement Leaderboards** in my game that is built **in MonoGame**. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find the GameHelper class and I cannot extend BaseGameActivity as described in [Google's how-to](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin), even though I have the google play services component installed (19.0.1)

The only other alternative is using the GoogleApiClient, which I tried:

```
public IGoogleApiClient apiClient;

GoogleApiClientBuilder builder = new GoogleApiClientBuilder(this);
builder.AddApi(GamesClass.Api)
       .AddApi(PlusClass.Api)
       .AddScope(GamesClass.ScopeGames)
       .AddScope(PlusClass.ScopePlusLogin);

apiClient = builder.Build();
```

But whenever I make a call to apiClient.Connect(), I get the following error:

```
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 7989): The Google Play services resources were not found. 
Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

I have cleaned and rebuilt, removed the component and added the references manually, changed the location of the project to the root of the drive, all to no avail. I'm out of ideas. Anyone have leaderboards running in MonoGame?

Comment: Have you added the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices component to your project?

Comment: Yep, I tried adding it via the component store as well as manually using the .dll references

Comment: Another thing you might like to check is whether GooglePlayServices are installed on the device by doing something like the following just to be sure, `if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable({context-here}) == 0)`.  Are you doing this by any chance also?

Comment: I don't have that check although I will add it for the release. I am sure that it is installed and up to date on the device though because I have AdMob & InAppBilling currently working

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote a [MonoGame project for Android](http://www.swipetapsmash.com/), which includes Leaderboard support. You can find the full source [here](https://code.google.com/p/mbhswipetapsmash/source/browse/trunk/), but I would recommend looking at [Activity1.cs](https://code.google.com/p/mbhswipetapsmash/source/browse/trunk/BumpSetSpike_Android/Activity1.cs) in particular. It is where I do most of the Google Play work.

You can also take a look at [GameOver.cs](https://code.google.com/p/mbhswipetapsmash/source/browse/trunk/BumpSetSpike/BumpSetSpike/Behaviour/GameOver.cs) to see an instance of the leaderboard getting a score submitted to it.

Answer (score 1):

That error message may not be the cause of your problem. I lifted the code and resources from BaseGame Utils and integrated it with my own project. I always get that message, and the game works perfectly.

I suggest you look carefully for any subsequent errors.

Comment: Thanks mate, I ended up creating an encapsulated class that implemented from Java.Lang.Object, IGoogleApiClientConnectionCallbacks, and IGoogleApiClientOnConnectionFailedListener. It solved the problem